# Custom names for aggregates

Tags: c#, nreco

In using the different aggregator factories is there a method or override that will allow for defining a custom name for the return label. For example, calling the SumAggregatoryFactory to sum the "Amount" field will return a row label of "Sum of Amount". What if instead we wanted it to be "Total Amount", "Total" or some other custom value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PivotData Toolkit writers (like `PivotTableHtmlWriter`) you can customize measure labels as you with FormatMeasureHeader property:

```
pvtHtmlWr.FormatMeasureHeader = (aggrFactory, measureIndex) => {
  // customize header by factory type or measure index
  return aggrFactory.ToString();
};
```

(see also: https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/format-pivot-table.aspx).

In case of custom rendering you can define your own formatting of measure names that takes into account aggregator type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **ResultAmount** class. That will return a description of the result, not the string. Something like this:

```
        class ResultAmount
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public decimal SumAmount { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Label}: {SumAmount}";
            }
        }
```

For different factories, the **Label** value may be different.
Then you have a factory:

```
        class TotalCalculations
        {
            public ResultAmount SumAggregatoryFactory()
            {
                return new ResultAmount
                {
                    Label = "Total",
                    SumAmount = 100
                };
            }
        }
```

And the point of calling factory:

```
    class BillingService
    {
        public void Print(TotalCalculations calc)
        {
            //when calling the method, you can use the standard Label                
            string original = calc.SumAggregatoryFactory().ToString();

             //or take only the sum and configure the result string yourself
            string custom = $"My message: {calc.SumAggregatoryFactory().SumAmount}";
        }
    }
```